# Display image saved as data type image in MSSQL

Tags: html, sql-server, base64, hex

I am currently creating a support system for my department and are using our old database for this.
When we receive a new ticket, the email is saved as an attachment and added to the database as the data type Image.

The content looks like this: (In this example an image) `0x21485A4C0A18000015EE76BA799CB69B03197D7707ABD4E877A300E576E03D3E5325600BEEE37A77564318DFFDC6173AF1D2D6A1D6706657F975E5AB924CD28594003C2674...` this example is 2k+ characters long.

Full example here: https://pastebin.com/x4KzSY5Y

My best guess is that this is some kind of hexadecimal. But honestly, I have no idea; I usually store files as blobs in MySQL.

What I have tried so far is to base64 encode the "hexadecimal." I have tried converting the content to various types. But so far, no luck, the image won't display correctly.

I would appreciate it if anyone knows how to display the image as an `<img>` in HTML.

Unfortunately, I cannot make any changes to the database. I know that the data type Image is swapped out for something else, can't quite remember what it is called.

I have never asked a question on StackOverflow before, so I am very sorry if it is unclear what I am asking.

Comment: The `image` data type has been deprecated in SQL Server for about 15 years and should not be used in new applications - use `varbinary(max)` columns instead. What you are looking at is a display representation of a byte array, i.e.: the first four elements are 0x21, 0x48, 0x5a, 0x4c. You would normally deserialize these columns as `byte[]` or `ByteArray` depending on the language of your SQL client application. I don't think this specific chunk of data is an image - the first four characters are `!HZL` which are not signature bytes for any image format I'm familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am reusing the database from the current system we have now. And cannot make any significant changes to it. And I have no idea how the file is converted to the bytes mentioned in my post, so I don't dare to change the data type.

I noticed that every single file stored in the database starts with the four elements; 0x21, 0x48, 0x5a and 0x4c. So I guess the file is stored as something else, then later on converted to present the content. However, I am not sure how to go forward from here. Any advice?

Comment: Find out what application was used to insert the data and try to get access to its source code to figure out how it actually constructed the data. If you pipe your example through Python's bytearray.fromhex() and write the result to a binary file on disc you can look at it with a hex editor, e.g. the Visual Studio Code extension "hexdump for VSCode". It's not very revealing, so it's probably some proprietary format, possibly compressed, possibly encrypted. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I did some digging through the application files and found some documentation. It turns out, it is compressed using LZH or also known as LHA, and I was able to extract the data. I appreciate the help, have a wonderful week :-)